# Allow apache to run a sphinx command

Tags: sudo

I need apache to be able to run sphinx index tool as I am building a web based interface to reindex and check various sphinx configs.

Currently I have added the following to `visudo`

```
Defaults:%apache !requiretty
Defaults:apache !requiretty
apache ALL=(sphinx) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/indexer, /usr/bin/indexer
```

The command I am running is:

```
exec sudo -u sphinx indextool --checkconfig --config /path/to/sphinx.conf
```

This is being run with PHP's `proc_open`

```
array(
    'stdin' => array('pipe', 'r'),
    'stdout' => array('pipe', 'w'),
    'stderr' => array('pipe', 'w'),
)
```

ERROR:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that I need to use the full path for the command

```
 exec sudo -u sphinx /usr/bin/indextool --checkconfig --config /path/to/sphinx.conf
```

Now everything works great